# Mocha Testing a post function

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js

Hmmm just double checking if I'm making some silly error, however doesn't seem like it. I just want this test to pass but it keeps giving me a timeout error. This module should work, it is sending mail correctly, but mocha keeps giving a timeout.

```
// describe('POST /api/mail', function() {
//  it('should successfully send mail', function(done) {
//      request(app)
//          .post('/api/mail')
//          .send(form)
//          .expect(200)
//          .end(function(err, res) {
//              if (err) return done(err);
//              done();
//          });
//  });
// });
```

This is the actual function being tested

```
'use strict';
var transporter = require('./transporter.js').transporter;

exports.sendMail = function(req, res){
    // setup e-mail data with unicode symbols
    var mailOptions = {
        from: req.body.name + ' <'+req.body.email+'>',
        to: 'test@gmail.com',
        subject: req.body.subject,
        text: req.body.message
    };

    // send mail with defined transport object
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err, info){
        if(err){
            res.status(400); //error
        }else{
            res.status(200); //success
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I think Mocha is waiting for sendMail result via callback. I have a similar sendMail, using nodemailer.js, in an application:

```
    function send(fr, to, sj, msg, callback){

    //...

    var transport = nodemailer.createTransport();

    console.log("Message content: "+msg);

    transport.sendMail({from:fr, to:to, subject: sj, text: "\r\n\r\n" + msg},
        function(err,response){
            if(err){
                callback(err);          
            }else{          
                callback(response);
            }
        });
};
```

In my test:

```
describe('when this example is tested',function(done){
it('should be sending an email', function(done){            
    mailSender.sendMail('test@test.es', 'Test', 'Test text', function(sent){            
        sent.should.be.ok;  
        done();
    });     
});
```

You get the sent in your callback and then Mocha can reach the done() method to indicate the test has finished.

Also, you can use [Supertest](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest) to test your endpoint. It should be something like this:

```
it('should return 200 on /api/mail', function(done) {

    supertest('http://localhost:3000').post('/api/mail').expect(200)
    .end(
        function(err, res) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }
            done();
        });
});
```